# Error in R system command while echoing long string

Tags: r, linux

Trying to write a certain input string using system() command in R. However it is failing with + sign as if command is not completed.

But deleting a certain part randomly, was able to run it.

```
system( "sudo echo 'statsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-126.78,i1=9.07,v2=341.16,i2=2.67,v3=-204.78,i3=-6.32 1557916955797397000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-171.62,i1=8.56,v2=347.97,i2=1.35,v3=-157.54,i3=-7.16 1557916955797898000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-213.26,i1=8.03,v2=345.71,i2=0.03,v3=-106.45,i3=-7.91 1557916955798398000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-249.82,i1=7.33,v2=333.84,i2=-1.25,v3=-54.12,i3=-8.55 1557916955798898000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-281.72,i1=6.56,v2=313.43,i2=-2.47,v3=-2.24,i3=-8.85 1557916955799399000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-329.42,i1=4.38,v2=257.89,i2=-4.66,v3=90.23,i3=-8.7 1557916955800269000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-343.94,i1=2.91,v2=214.3,i2=-5.69,v3=138.46,i3=-8.23 1557916955800769000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-350.6,i1=1.5,v2=165.64,i2=-6.5,v3=183.03,i3=-7.65 1557916955801270000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-347.9,i1=-0.02,v2=114.14,i2=-7.37,v3=223.18,i3=-6.99 1557916955801771000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-336.59,i1=-1.39,v2=62.16,i2=-7.98,v3=257.67,i3=-6.27 1557916955802271000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-316.4,i1=-2.78,v2=9.36,i2=-8.48,v3=289.13,i3=-5.4 1557916955802772000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-288.25,i1=-4.18,v2=-42.73,i2=-8.73,v3=315.34,i3=-4.24 1557916955803273000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-246.49,i1=-5.3,v2=-95.83,i2=-8.47,v3=332.18,i3=-2.95 1557916955803774000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-201.12,i1=-6.38,v2=-143.22,i2=-8.18,v3=342.65,i3=-1.55 1557916955804275000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-151.05,i1=-7.31,v2=-187.98,i2=-7.75,v3=344.69,i3=-0.21 1557916955804776000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-97.91,i1=-8.05,v2=-228.31,i2=-7.11,v3=336.2,i3=1.17 1557916955805277000\n'" )
```

This is not running

However if I run this command deleting randomly some part, it is clearly executed.

```
system( "sudo echo 'statsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-126.78,i1=9.07,v2=341.16,i2=2.67,v3=-204.78,i3=-6.32 1557916955797397000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-171.62,i1=8.56,v2=347.97,i2=1.35,v3=-157.54,i3=-7.16 1557916955797898000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-213.26,i1=8.03,v2=345.71,i2=0.03,v3=-106.45,i3=-7.91 1557916955798398000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-249.82,i1=7.33,v2=333.84,i2=-1.25,v3=-54.12,i3=-8.55 1557916955798898000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-281.72,i1=6.56,v2=313.43,i2=-2.47,v3=-2.24,i3=-8.85 1557916955799399000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-329.42,i1=4.38,v2=257.89,i2=-4.66,v3=90.23,i3=-8.7 1557916955800269000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-343.94,i1=2.91,v2=214.3,i2=-5.69,v3=138.46,i3=-8.23 1557916955800769000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-350.6,i1=1.5,v2=165.64,i2=-6.5,v3=183.03,i3=-7.65 1557916955801270000\nstatsd_vmart_4d,company=prop-new,machine=EdgeMotor1,machineId=machine-1ad271a0-d6a4-11e8-8f3a-433749296f72,subassemblyinstance=motorSense1,datatype=eventtrap,collector=pf1,param=rawvalues v1=-347.9,i1=-0.02,v2=114.14,i2=-7.37,v3=223.18,i3=-6.99 1557916955801771000\n'" )
```

This is not due to length issue as I have seen it working with longer text.

Comment: Have you tried `system2`? Note that the call is different. It must be a command *without*  arguments, that are passed in another argument.

Comment: @RuiBarradas what will be the change for that. Can you please help on that ?

Comment: You must put the arguments to `echo` in a vector of character strings. You have a long command line, break it: `system2("echo", args = c("$PATH", "$R_HOME"))`.

Comment: It is not helping. What I have done is that instead of writing the whole string at once, I am writing within a loop.